# shortest code to center a number of columns

Tags: r

I'm working on a data set with a number of variables, some of which I want to center. The colnames which I want to center are stored in a list:

```
cols <- c('mahalanobis', 'response.sd') 
df <- data.frame(subject = c(1,2,3), mahalanobis = c(4,3,1), response.time = c(4,1,5), random.var = c(2,5,7), response.sd = c(3,2,1))

> df
  subject mahalanobis response.time random.var response.sd
1       1           4             4          2           3
2       2           3             1          5           2
3       3           1             5          7           1
```

The code i'm currently using is:

```
df <- df %>% 
   group_by(subject) %>% 
   mutate(mahalanobis.c = mahalanobis - mean(mahalanobis),
          response.sd.c = response.sd - mean(response.sd))
```

Now, i'm wondering if there is a way to skip writing the same calculation within that `mutate()` function, but just with different variable names. So for instance type the centering line once and use the names within the `cols` list to do the rest.

Or are there more efficient ways of tackling this problem?

Comment: `summarise_all()` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `mutate_at` to apply the function to multiple columns.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(subject) %>%  mutate_at(vars(cols), list(c = ~. - mean(.)))
```

Comment: Aha, that solves the problem! But I would like to have colnames that end with '.c' instead of '_c', is there a way to change this?

Comment: @jorangeeraerts I guess `dplyr` adds underscore by default in the names so not sure you can change it directly. You can try `.c` instead of just `c` in `list` if that is ok. However, you can use `rename_at` like `df %>% 
  group_by(subject) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(cols), list(c = ~. - mean(.))) %>%
  rename_at(vars(ends_with('_c')), ~sub('_c', '.c', .))`

Answer (score 0):

With `base R` wee can do

```
df[paste0(cols, "_c")] <- df[cols] - rowMeans(df[cols])
```